# Azure DevOps private Linux agent - YAML pipeline checkout failing - can fix with "git config --global --unset http.extraHeader" but not early enough

Tags: authentication, azure-devops

**We have an issue regarding the following:**

- Azure DevOps Linux Private Agent
- Possible issue with corrupt / stale bearer token
- Can be fixed with this command by logging onto the box but this is not convenient: `git config --global --unset http.extraHeader`
- Can be fixed with this command as part of script in YAML: `git config --global --unset http.extraHeader` but not early enough. (*See next comment below*).
- I can't run this command early enough in the pipeline YAML to clear the header as checkout is not controlled by me.
- It generally only happens if a previous run fails at some point on the same private agent

  ```
   Syncing repository: test-project-azure-workspace (Git)
   git version
   git version 2.26.0
   git lfs version
   git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)
   git config --get remote.origin.url
   git clean -ffdx
   git reset --hard HEAD
   HEAD is now at 5f9fd24 sql mi
   git config gc.auto 0
   git config --get-all http.https://xxxxxxx@dev.azure.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/_git/test-project-azure-workspace.extraheader
   git config --get-all http.proxy
   git config http.version HTTP/1.1
   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" -c http.proxy="http://10.XXX.XXX.XX:80" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --unshallow origin
   * Couldn't find host dev.azure.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
  ```

**Here is the code that can remedy the symptom:**

```
- script: |
 echo '======================================================================'
 echo 'list all of git config values for your convenience:'
 echo '======================================================================'
 git config --list 
 echo '======================================================================'
 existing_header=$(git config  --get http.extraHeader)
 if [ ${#existing_header} -gt 0 ]
 then  
  echo 'We found the http.extraHeader'
  echo 'un-setting extra header: http.extraHeader '
  git config --global --unset http.extraHeader
 else
  echo 'no extra header: http.extraHeader was not found. Nothing to unset '
 fi
condition: always() 
workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s'
displayName: 'Remove Git Authentication'
```

Obviously, I am treating the symptom and not the cause so any pointers as to what is causing this would be a great help.

Comment: Hi RuSs, you can run the cmd ./config.sh remove to remove the agent and re-configure an agent, then run the cmd config.sh --proxyurl https://<proxyserver>:<proxyport>; --proxyusername “<username>” --proxypassword “<password>”  to re-configure it.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thanks for your message, I am not sure how that relates to my explicit question about the header bearer token possibly being corrupt / stale. 
I don't want to re-configure the agent every time this happens

Comment: Hi @RuSs, Could you please try it and then kindly share the result here? Since I cannot reproduce this issue, please also set the variable system.debug to true, then share the full log here. Thanks.

Comment: @RuSs, It seems LFS doesn't include extra header from git config, please try to update the git version on the private agent.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT thanks for that. I will look into this soon but I am miss-understanding after reading through the documentation. How will I authenticate without the extra header and therefore the BEARER token?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "cleaning" job at the start of your pipeline that uses the `checkout` task with `none` as the repo to checkout. This will allow you to then run the cleaning script.

```yaml
- job: cleanAgent
  steps: 
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
      echo "Put your git cleaner here"
```

A better option is really to clean the agent after you are done by running a cleaning task with a condition of `always()` at the end of your pipeline. This can be hard if other people also use the agents and don't clean-up though.

```yaml
- job: cleanupAgents
  condition: always()
  steps:
    - script: |
      echo "Put your git cleaner here"
```